# Can Nested or Inner class by an @Entity in JPA?

Tags: java, nested, jpa-2.0

Can I and Should I make nested, inner classes an @Entity? For example:

```
@Entity
public class EnclosingOne {
  @Entity
  public class NestedOne extends EnclosingOne {
  }
  @Entity
  public static class InnerOne extends EnclosingOne {
  }
}
```

Or:

```
public class EnclosingOne {
  @Entity
  public class NestedOne extends EnclosingOne {
  }
  @Entity
  public static class InnerOne extends EnclosingOne {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The JPA 2.1 specifications, paragraph 2.1, page 23, say:

> The entity class must be a top-level class.

Comment: Unfortunately  :(. Thanks for Your answer. I wanted to be sure, cause eclipse doesn't pointed this as a Error.